# `cf push -c null` does not work as expected

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I was using `cf push -c null` to clear the command of application running in Bluemix. Recently I noticed that `cf push -c null` does not clear the command. It resets it to the first one being used.

For instance:

1. I create an app without command
2. I set command using `cf push -c "node app.js"`
3. I try to reset it using `cf push -c null`

The app command was reset to null some time ago. 
Now, it is changed to `node app.js`.

Was this changed on purpose? Is there a different way to set command to null?
Note that REST calls made by cf cli did not change. It still sends command: "" to reset the app command.

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: version 6.11.1-4ef66f6-2015-04-20T14:13:38+00:00

Comment: I checked the older version too. And both make the same REST calls for cf push -c null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem. What I did is:

1. cf push myapp -c "node app.js"
   The output says: App myapp was started using this command `node app.js`
2. cf push myapp -c null
   The output says: App myapp was started using this command `./vendor/initial_startup.rb`
3. If I set CF_TRACE=true, and do "cf app myapp", I can see "command":null in one of the responses.

Is it possible that your repush was picking up a manifest.yml that you have in the app root folder and that is setting the command?

Comment: What is your target Bluemix?

Comment: Production. I saw on some other forums that this may be a defect with CloudFoundry v205. Bluemix Production is not running v205.

Comment: I was checking against one of dev versions (stage1). I will check PROD again.

Comment: So PROD does not have the issue (yet). We need to make sure that the faulty CF version is not promoted to PROD.